# asp.net date time is not result same

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

this is the property I have :

```
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public TimeSpan StartingTime { get; set; }
```

now in controller I will check if the starting time is less then now

```
var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
   return View(db.SchoolTime.ToList().Where(a => a.StartingTime < now );
```

here even the starting-time is less then now in database but not returning list to vew

I think it's because **Starting-time** is lik(09:00:00) but the **now** is like 09:10:00:12312312

please help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of the '<' condition.
Try changing the code to:

```
return View(db.SchoolTime.Where(a => a.StartingTime < now).ToList());
```

Where condition doesn't get applied unless you enumerate over the collection.
ToList() will help you do that.
 
Else it will execute once the collection is enumerated in the View.

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
DateTime parsedDate;
string pattern = ;
DateTime.TryParseExact(StartingTime, "MM-dd-yy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
parsedDate.TimeOfDay;// out put in your format MM:HH:SS
```

Inorder to make the above code to work you need to add using `System.Globalization;` namespace.

Update 1 :
As per your code

```
var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

returns **00:00:00** every time because it should be assigned when you are creating the DateTime object itself.

So use this

```
var now = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss")
return View(db.SchoolTime.ToList().Where(a => a.StartingTime < now );
```

Comment: The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.